# SwiftUI fade-in on disappear

Tags: swiftui

I'm animating an overlay for one of my views and the expected animation is:

**On appear:**

1. Start out with opacity = 1
2. Animate to opacity = 0

*As I undertand, this is fairly easy to do with a boolean state variable that gets set within an `onAppear` and a standard animation*

Here's where things get tough

**On disappear:**

1. Start out with `opacity = 0`
2. Animate to `opacity = 1`

This isn't possible to do within a `onDisappear` because the state change won't get animated as the object is disappearing

---

I know people use `.transition` for similar animations, but `.transition` forces the opacity to animate to 0 on disappear and to 1 on appear.

Comment: what triggers the disappearing of the view?

Comment: as far as I understand you do need to use the .transition modifier.  I'm currently struggling with this too, since I guess I'm not doing it right.